# How to prove $\vdash\neg P\to (P\to Q)$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove,

> $$\vdash\neg P\to (P\to Q)$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are arbitrary but otherwise fixed formulas.

The only axioms and rule of inference that I can use are,

> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 1.}}\  P\to (Q\to P)$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 2.}}\  (S\to (P\to Q))\to((S\to P)\to (S\to Q))$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Axiom 3.}}\  (\neg Q\to\neg P)\to(P\to Q)$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{Rule of Inference.}}$ [Modus Ponens](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8i9j2vZHPAhVLn5QKHVpiC0YQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FModus_ponens&usg=AFQjCNGjiX3Tbw5h49jNotuefUM9xvBIDw).

I know that in Angelo Margaris's book *First Order Mathematical Logic* there is a proof (page 53) but as I have mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927952/how-to-prove-vdash-p-to-p), the dot notation seems very confusing and translating them to the nested parentheses notation seems very difficult to me. So, I am trying on my own to prove the result.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you use modus nullens?

Comment: @fleablood: No.

Comment: -P -> (-Q->-P) axiom1. (-Q->-P)->(P->Q)axiom 2.  -P->(P->Q) mp. And... wait  what's that mark in the beginning mean?

Comment: Can we use --P =P?

Comment: (+1 for stating your rules and axioms up front). Do you have the Deduction Theorem available?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: No.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abbreviate $a = \lnot P$, $b = \lnot Q \to \lnot P$, and $c = P \to Q$. Then

> $\color{crimson}{\text{1.}}\  a\to b \color{crimson}{\ \ \ \text{by axiom 1}}$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{2.}}\  b\to c \color{crimson}{\ \ \ \text{by axiom 3}}$

and we need to deduce $a \to c$. The thing that ultimately is going to produce this is

> $\color{crimson}{\text{3.}}\  (a \to (b \to c)) \to ((a \to b) \to (a \to c)) \color{crimson}{\ \ \ \text{by axiom 2}}$

Note that we're already very close: we just need to deduce $a \to (b \to c)$ from $b \to c$ and apply modus ponens twice. So

> $\color{crimson}{\text{4.}}\  (b\to c) \to (a \to (b \to c)) \color{crimson}{\ \ \ \text{by axiom 1}}$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{5.}}\  a \to (b \to c) \color{crimson}{\ \ \ \text{by modus ponens on 2 and 4}}$

And, as promised, we finish by applying modus ponens twice.

> $\color{crimson}{\text{6.}}\  (a \to b) \to (a \to c) \color{crimson}{\ \ \ \text{by modus ponens on 3 and 5}}$
>
> $\color{crimson}{\text{7.}}\  a \to c \color{crimson}{\ \ \ \text{by modus ponens on 1 and 6}}$

Comment: Wait... at first glance it looked like you encoded a proof of {(A$\to$B), (B$\to$C)} $\vdash$ (A$\to$C) in this proof.  Except, we'd have to interpret 1. and 2. as assumptions.  Then again, I feel proving that rule a bit unnecessary for this system, since ((A$\to$B)$\to$((C$\to$A)$\to$(C$\to$B))) is 3 condensed detachments away from the axioms, or only a few more steps if we use substitution and detachment.

Answer (score 1):

1) $\lnot P \rightarrow (\lnot Q\rightarrow \lnot P) $ Axiom 1

2) $(\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P)\rightarrow (P\rightarrow Q) $ Axiom 3.

3) $[(\lnot Q \rightarrow \lnot P)\rightarrow (P\rightarrow Q)] \rightarrow \{[\lnot P \rightarrow (\lnot P\rightarrow \lnot Q)]\rightarrow [\lnot P \rightarrow(P\rightarrow Q)]\}$ Axiom 2.

4) $[\lnot P \rightarrow (\lnot P\rightarrow \lnot Q)]\rightarrow [\lnot P \rightarrow(P\rightarrow Q)]$ Modus ponens.  2 and 3 combined.

5) $\lnot P \rightarrow(P\rightarrow Q)$ Modus ponens 1 and 4 combined.

====

I originally mistated modus ponens.  Which is $A; (A \rightarrow B); \implies B$ whereas what I used was $(A \rightarrow B);(B\rightarrow C)\implies (A \rightarrow C)$ which is similar but different.

We can prove that I think:

$B \rightarrow C$ given

so by axiom 2 $(A \rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$

$(A \rightarrow B)$ given

So $A \rightarrow C$: modus ponens.

===

As long as we are proving things I might as well prove modus nolens.

$A \rightarrow B; \lnot B$.

The $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A)$ Axiom 3

So $\lnot B \rightarrow \lnot A$ modus ponens.

So $\lnot A$.  Modus ponens.  Hence modus nolens is valid.  Hey, this proving stuff is neat!

But I am assuming it is given $\lnot \lnot P = P$.  Is that a given?  If not we must prove it before anything.

What are we given as basic tautologies?  Do we know $P\rightarrow P$, $P \lor \lnot P$ etc?

Comment: Modus Ponens says that from $\vdash$($\alpha$$\to$$\beta$) as well as $\vdash$$\alpha$ we may infer $\vdash$$\beta$.  I believe you used from $\vdash$($\alpha$$\to$$\beta$) as well as $\vdash$($\beta$$\to$$\gamma$) we may infer $\vdash$($\alpha$$\to$$\gamma$)

Comment: However, once you have $\alpha\to\beta$ and $\beta\to\gamma$, you can infer $\alpha\to(\beta\to\gamma)$ by A1 and MP, and then a suitable instance of A2 (and two more MP) allows you to reason from $\alpha\to(\beta\to\gamma)$ and $\alpha\to\beta$ to $\alpha\to\gamma$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not sure I follow.  But, is your *full* proof more than six steps?

Comment: I think I now have it in 4 steps.

Comment: Nope.  I had it in 5.

Comment: But then I assume $\lnot \lnot P = P$.  Perhaps we need so more steps to work that in.

Comment: Step 3) is not an instance of axiom 2.  1) doesn't match the antecedent of 4).

Comment: Gad, I keep doing cut and past errors!

Comment: That was a cut and paste error.  It should be fixed now.  But I'm still assuming $\lnot \lnot P = P$.  I'm not sure that can be proven with just these axioms

Comment: No, the problems I pointed out still hold.  Additionally, you only have modus ponens as a rule of inference.  You don't have some rule that allows for equality replacement (and equality qualifies as a predicate).  You also didn't write an instance of Axiom 3 in your commentary.  I am however laughing that you've talked about modus *nolens*.  I believe you meant modus tollens, but nolens is actually a Latin word.  By talking about modus nolens, you've talked about the "not wanting mode/way".  http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/verb:nolle

Comment: I don't understand (3). How does it follow from Axiom 2?

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's recast those schema as well-formed formulas.  This makes substitutions mechanical and less error-prone.  Or more easily corrected when errors occur.

Axiom 1 (P$\to$(Q$\to$P))

Axiom 2 ((S$\to$(P$\to$Q))$\to$((S$\to$P)$\to$(S$\to$Q)))

Axiom 3 (($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P)$\to$(P$\to$Q))

We want to get to ($\neg$P$\to$(P$\to$Q)).  If we look at Axiom 3, it's consequent matches the consequent of the target formula.  So, how do we get rid of ($\neg$Q$\to$$\lnot$P) and put $\lnot$P in front of (P$\to$Q)?  Or can we do one of those two?

Well, *were it the case* that (P$\to$Q) was a theorem, then Axiom 1 would allow us to put any formula, such as $\neg$P, in front of (P$\to$Q).  Axiom 1 can also get used to infer any consequent of some formula $\omega$ if the antecedent of $\omega$ can get derived from Axiom 1 by substitution.  Axiom 2 "tells" us that if we have some S in front of a conditional $\chi$, we can transfer S to the front of the antecedent of $\chi$ and the front of the consequent of $\chi$.  I use $\alpha$/$\beta$ to indicate that $\alpha$ gets substituted with $\beta$.  When I write $\alpha$ * $\beta$, both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ indicate equiform formulas.  Thus, putting that all together...

:Axiom 1 P/(($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P)$\to$(P$\to$Q)), Q/$\neg$P * 1

1 ((($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P)$\to$(P$\to$Q))$\to$($\neg$P$\to$(($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P)$\to$(P$\to$Q))))

:1 * (Axiom 3$\to$2)

2 ($\neg$P$\to$(($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P)$\to$(P$\to$Q)))

:Axiom 2 S/$\neg$P, P/($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P), Q/(P$\to$Q) * 3

3 (($\neg$P$\to$(($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P)$\to$(P$\to$Q)))$\to$(($\neg$P$\to$($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P))$\to$($\neg$P$\to$(P$\to$Q))))

:3 * (2$\to$4)

4 (($\neg$P$\to$($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P))$\to$($\neg$P$\to$(P$\to$Q)))

:Axiom 1 P/$\neg$P, Q/$\neg$Q * 5

5 ($\neg$P$\to$($\neg$Q$\to$$\neg$P))

:4 * (5$\to$6)

6 ($\neg$P$\to$(P$\to$Q))

The above is a bit of false [history](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1928125/11300) if read as indicating how I found this proof, but perhaps it also offers a bit more metalogical insight.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Use Axiom 1 in the form $\neg P \to (\neg Q \to \neg P)$ and Axiom 3.

Comment: What is Axiom 4?

Comment: Dang.  This is a weird phone app.  I read the post and the app gave me no indication that someone had posted an answer 15 minutes earlier.  I'm sorry I answered basically the same thing you did 19 minutes later.

Comment: @user170039 It was meant to be Axiom 3.

Comment: It's slightly more involved than that.  -P => (-Q=>-P) and (-Q => -P) => (P => Q) but we don't have a rule of inference that A=>B and B=>C means that A=>C.  We have to prove that or incorporate a few more steps.